# Command Line Authorization and GitHub

Tags: parse-platform

When I try to follow the tutorial at [Cloud Code Guide](https://parse.com/docs/cloud_code_guide), it says to create a new app with parse and login. After entering my user name and password, it says "Authorization Failed." I'm 100% sure I'm using the correct email and password **for GitHub**. How can I use the command line tool if my account is linked with GitHub?

I'm using the latest version of the parse command line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Log in to parse.com and go to your account page.  Click the update button and set a password on your Parse account.  It should allow you to set one without asking for a 'current' password if you signed up via GitHub.  Now you can use that password to log in with the Parse CLI.